# How do I find a the max length of a Combobox?

Tags: api, data-types

I'm creating an application that pulls down some records into a SQL table. The application recreates the table if it detects any changes to the Salesforce schema. For string-like datatypes (picklist, textarea, etc.), I'm getting the field's maximum length from the field.length property returned from the partner API's DescribeSObject call.

The unusual behavior I'm seeing is that the ActivityHistory table's Subject field (a combobox) says that it has a length of 80. However, I have plenty of records with >80 characters. I've also seen that [the max is actually 255 now](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br7oAAC).

So I'm either looking in the wrong place for the field length, or I'm missing some key piece of information for getting the correct length. How do I find the "real" length of this field?

Answer (score 0):

Subject field on Activity History is a "standard field" and is designed to be no more than 80 characters leaving us with no ability to modify the character limit.

The Subject field for Activity was increased to 255 char in winter 11.

[image: You can verify the individual metadata of each object using Workbench]

[image: Size of the Subject field is 80 char]

The only workaround is to truncate the subject size to fit Salesforce field size of 80 Chars. ActivityHistory is a read-only object, so you cannot create custom fields too.

Comment: Hi Varun, I appreciate your answer. However, I'm not asking for the length of the field, I'm asking how to accurately find the length of a field with the API. For most fields, using the DescribeSObject works, but in this case it incorrectly tells me that the field length is 80 characters when it is actually 255.

Comment: Hi Eric, My understanding is that the native subject field on Activity History is 80 and not 255. 

In my dev org, I verified the field size for Subject field on Task and it is 255 char. Name field on Account is 255 but Subject field on Activity History is 80.

Comment: Hi Varun, though the metadata says that the field is only 80 characters long, the records I have are up to 255 characters long. The actual max length is 255 despite what the metadata says.